# Session automatically destroys in Express JS, mongodb, Node js application

Tags: node.js, express

When i close the broswer, the session gets destroyed automatically. Following is the code in my app.js file.

```
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoSessions = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

app.use(session({
secret: '007',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
duration: 40*60 *1000,
activeDuration: 10*60*1000,
store: new MongoSessions({
    url: db_url
})
}));
```

When user logs in , i store the user id of user in a session. When a user again accesses the system, it will redirect him to directly to home page. To check this:

```
exports.indexPage = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.session.userid == null) {
    res.render('login');
} else {
    res.render('index');
}
```

};

It works fine when i keep the browser open but close all tabs and again access the application. When i close the browser and again access the application, it redirects me to login page.

Comment: How do you know the session is destroyed?

Comment: @Richard. I edited my question. Any idea why session destroys when browser closes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `duration` and `activeDuration` are meant to be, but they aren't valid options for `express-session`.

Since you're not setting a `maxAge` value for the session cookie, it automatically becomes limited to the current browser session, meaning that it will be destroyed when you close the browser (as you already noticed).

To prevent that, configure a [maximum age](https://github.com/expressjs/session#maxage) (in milliseconds):

```
app.use(session({
  cookie : {
    maxAge : 40 * 60 * 1000
  },
  secret: '007',
  ...
}));
```

Comment: Tried it. still facing the same issue  :(

Comment: @Kaishah start by checking if the cookie is persisted in your browser (using  its dev tools).

Comment: If the cookie is still there, the issue may be with your session store configuration. Try setting `DEBUG=express-session` as environment variable and restart the server, it should show a bunch of debug messages that may point to a possible cause of your problems.

Comment: I am very sorry for misinterpretation. Yes.. cookie gets deleted as soon as i close the browser.

Comment: @Kaishah that's strange; with the example code in my answer, it should be a persistent cookie lasting 40 minutes.